# Google Apps Script > Google Forms - Automatically sending email to address on cell each time a response is submitted

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

don't know if this is the right place to ask for this:

I'm currently working on a in-house control system in Google Sheets. Everytime a sales rep enters a work order, this work order with info filled in the form needs to be send to the designer team via email.

The form contains a field for the designer's ID ([The form is here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdcjAlCmat6EDPjztrX9k4o404r6mLfgpTAtSrSiV3m3u92Fg/viewform)).

I've got two problems, first the designer's emails are in a different sheet and the email must be send to the designated designer each time a response is submitted.

This is the spreadsheet I am working on [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14i3bMuVWYJyjcQjtMbhjaLJnKDnNyKbKvDNJ2puuF2s/edit?usp=sharing).

The email must contain all the fields in the form.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: The basic idea is that you would pull that sheet up in apps script, sleect the range containing the emails and IDs, find the appropriate ID match, grab the email, and send the email with Mailapp.

You should do some research into apps script code to get started with form triggers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for asking for general advice.

Comment: If you've tried something and it doesn't work, edit that into the question so that we have something to look at :)